# How do I use the different types of command blocks in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’ve tried everything, from research to first-hand, but nothing worked. I’ve tried every bit of advice but it never happens, which is a massive blockade in my visions for what I want to create. I can’t use the `stack` command as it’s not available in the Bedrock Edition, nor can I seem to activate `chain` or `repeat` blocks.

Does anyone know how I can use the command blocks `chain` and `repeat` in Minecraft Bedrock Edition? Or is it that everything I wanna do is simply just not available in this edition?

Comment: Hi Zukuio, welcome to Arqade! What is "first-hand", exactly? Do you simply mean you tried using these blocks in-game? And can you show us what research you have done?

Comment: @zukuio What is the `stack` command? I don't believe this is a command in Java Edition, nor Bedrock. From a little bit of research, it seems that it may be from a mod like WorldEdit, meaning it wouldn't be supported in Bedrock, at least not without a similar addon.

Answer (score 3):

There are three command block types in both Bedrock Edition (previously known as Pocket Edition) and Java Edition (on PC):

- `Impulse`, the default when you place down a command block, where the command block is orange.
- `Chain`, where the command block is a cyan/green color.
- `Repeat`, where the command block is purple.

You can change the type of command block by tapping on it and then select the drop down menu, or by specifying the type of command block in the `/give` command:

`/give @s chain_command_block`
`/give @s repeat_command_block`

These other command block types are a bit more complicated than the default type, but basically, a repeat command block repeats the command entered for as long as it is powered, and the chain command is used in sequences of command blocks, and fires after the command block behind it has run. They have to placed so that all the arrows are facing in the same direction to make sure that they actually run.

I highly recommend checking out the official [Bedrock Creator Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/) for more in  depth information, and info that is specific to this version of Minecraft. These articles should be helpful:

- [Getting Started with Command Blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/commandblocks) - Basics with command blocks, including repeat and chain.
- [Introduction to Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/commandsintroduction) - Basics with commands overall.
- [Popular Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/commandspopularcommands)
- [How To Make a "Complete the Monument" World](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/commandshowtomakeactmworld) - You can get some practice with different types of commands by following this tutorial.

Additionally, you can check out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/differencesbetweenbedrockandjava) if you want to learn more about the history and differences between Minecraft versions. If you're still a little confused about using the different command block types and want a more visual explanation, try a YouTube tutorial like [this one](https://youtu.be/mH56KTbTatA).

---

Feel free to ask any more questions you have either in the comments here or in a separate question, just make sure to include enough detail that we can understand your problem and how we can help. Good luck on your command journey!

Answer (score -2):

I think due to the limited abilities In pocket edition, I don't think commands like that are possible. Then again, I'm also not an expert on command blocks and especially not on pocket edition, so I may very well be incorrect.